# Maximum possible number of elements in a subset given a condition

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let $B$ be a subset of $A$ such that no element in $B$ is twice the other. Find the maximum number of elements possible in $B$ if $A=\{1,2,...,n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $A=\{1,2,\dots,n\},$ the optimal choice for $B$ is the set of all numbers in $A$ of the form $(2x+1)2^{2y}$ where $x$ and $y$ and nonnegative integers, and then the number of elements in $B$ is
$$|B|=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{n+2^{2k}}{2^{2k+1}}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_4n\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{n+2^{2k}}{2^{2k+1}}\right\rfloor.$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the chains $\{2^ka \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\} \cap \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ where $a$  is odd. Membership of an element in a chain doesn't affect membership in a different chain. So maximizing the size of $B$ is akin to maximizing the size of each chain. This can easily be done by choosing only even $k$ for each chain. The maximal size for each chain is then $$\left\lceil \frac{\lfloor \log_2 (n/a) \rfloor + 1}{2} \right\rceil$$

Then sum over all odd $a$ in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: Whoops, ran through it rather quickly, I'll fix it...